# How to modify content of default artifact with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to know how can I modify the default artifact in order to have the following structure for my artifact published with SBT:

```
my_artifact.zip
            -config/default.conf
            -my_package.jar
```

It is actually quite straightforward case. I want my final artifact contain those two and to be able to change the type to zip. I have tried to access the default's artifact mappings as next without any results:

```
artifact in (Compile, publish) := {
  val previous: Artifact = (artifact in (Compile, publish)).value
  previous.withName("test_artifact"  + "." + previous.extension)
  previous.withType("zip")
  previous.withExtension("zip")
  previous
}

mappings in packagedArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) += {
  file(s"${baseDirectory.value.getPath}/src/main/config/current.conf") -> "config/current.conf"
}
```

Any suggestions how could I achieve this?

Comment: Any ideas someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more about SBT I realized that I do not need to modify the artifacts at all. Actually I managed to change the directory structure just by using sbt-assembly in combination with a post-build task:

```
lazy val postBuild  = taskKey[Unit]("post build")
postBuild := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val source = (baseDirectory.value / "src/main/config/current.conf")
  val target = baseDirectory.value / "out"/ "config/current.conf"

  log.info(s"Copying ${source.getPath} to ${target.getPath}")
  IO.copyFile(source, target)
  None
}

lazy val finalBuild =  taskKey[Unit]("final build")

finalBuild := {
  Def.sequential(assembly.toTask, postBuild.toTask).value
}
```

postBuild is responsible for the content modifications. In finalBuild I execute stb-assembly task and then postBuild sequentially

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is that you are returning "previous" which is immutable. Thus it does exactly what it was going to do before and the changes you make are lost. I was able to modify the artifact using the following code

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.4",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    )),
    name := "sbtartifact",
    artifact in (Compile, packageBin) := {
       val previous = (artifact in (Compile, packageBin)).value
       previous.withType("bundle").withExtension("bundle")
    },
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )
```

Note that I am not returning previous but `previous.withType("bundle").withExtension("bundle")` which is the copy of previous post the mutation.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the suggestion. I would like though to be able to access the structure of the artifact that will be generated. For example I want to add the config folder to the artifact. This is the major issue that I am facing since I dont know the right way to do it. I tried through _packagedArtifact_ but without results